# How to write a very long sum in a fitness function for global optimisation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, sum

I a struggling writing a fully parametrised fitness function for the global optimisation toolbox in matlab.

**Approach:**

```
[x fvall,exitflag,output]=ga(fitnessfcn,nvars,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

I have a fitness function that I call with

```
fitnessfcn=@fitnessTest;
```

hence, the function is stated in a separate file.

**Problem:**
My issue is now that my optimisation is a simple but super long sum like

cost=f1*x1+f2x2+...fnxn

n should be parameterised (384 at the moment). In all matlab help files, the objective function is always short and neat like

```
y = 100 * (x(1)^2 - x(2)) ^2 + (1 - x(1))^2;
```

I have tried several approaches "writing" the objective function intelligently, but then, I cannot call the function correctly:

if I write the fitness function manually (for fi=1)

```
function y = simple_fitness(x)
y = x(1)+ x(2)+ x(3)+ x(4)+ x(5)+ x(6)+ x(7)+ x(8);
```

the global optimisation works

But if I use my automated approach:

```
    n = 8; %# number of function handles
parameters = 1:1:n;
store = cell(2,3);

for i=1:n
  store{1,i} = sprintf('x(%i)',parameters(i));
  store{2,i} = '+'; %# operator
end

%# combine such that we get
%# sin(t)+sin(t/2)+sin(t/4)
funStr = [store{1:end-1}];%# ignore last operator

endFunction=';';

%functionHandle = str2func(funStr)
y=strcat(funStr,endFunction)
```

matlab does not recognise the function properly:

error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
>
> Error in fcnvectorizer (line 14)
>               y(i,:) = feval(fun,(pop(i,:)));

thanks! I cannot write the objective function by hand as I will have several hundred variables.

Comment: What dimensions has the returned value from `feval(fun,(pop(i,:))):` and what dimension has `y`?

Comment: Ye gawds. An extreme case of using a mack truck to carry a pea to Boston. Rather than using a hack like this, learn some very basic matlab tools, like sum. Even a loop in an m-file would be easier than this.

Comment: you are right @woodchips. Sorry...classic case of turning a deaf ear to new (old) ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the sum(x) directly using function handle, instead of writing all indexes, do: `fitnessfcn = @(x) sum(x)`.

Comment: I might be a bit late to this party, but using `fitnessfcn=@sum` is even simpler:)